# How to read the values from the parameter, embeeded schem in C#

Tags: schema, c#

I have created component using schema A it consists of embeedded schema type. The embedded schema has two fields the `keyname` and `keyvalue`.

Created parameter schema which contain the field called `componentpath`.
That parameter schema is assocaiated to the tbb.

1. I want to read the parameter value.
2. Load the component and read the values of the component but want to read for particular keyaname this is the keyvalue.

Comment: Hi k951, welcome to Stack Exchange. This question doesn't contain enough information to help. Please try and be more specific about your issue and include code samples and what you did to try and solve the problem. Also see the FAQs for more detail.

Comment: Rob Stevenson Legget i have edit the question

Comment: Would you please read the FAQ and let us know...what you really want to do and where/which area of SDL Tridion. From your question, nothing can be concluded as what do you want to do

Comment: i think this question is now accepted and hoping answer for it

Comment: @PankajGaur i think the question looks good accepting answer :)

Comment: Yes, This looks much better now, thanks for updating :)